# MongoDB sorting to put certain records last based on lookup

Tags: mongodb, sorting, database-design, database, nosql

I've got some basic sorting going in MongoDB, of the kind:

```
 db.collection.find().sort( { age: -1 } );
```

However, what if I want to create a more advanced sorting type?

For instance, this data:

```
 [
  {name    :'obj1',
   category:'shoes'},
  {name    :'obj2',
   category:'hats'},
  {name    :'obj3',
   category:'jumpers'},
  {name    :'obj4',
   category:'shoes'}
 ]
```

Say I have this data and I want to sort it so that anything with `category:'shoes'` appears last. Is that possible and how is it achieved?

Comment: Do you mean that `"shoes"` would always be last, even if there was a `category` that would normally have sorted after it? Like, `"tennis"`? Because, if you are, I'd add an answer saying it's not practical on the DB in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow.. In your example above, you could just sort by category

```
db.collection.find().sort( { category : 1 } )
```

That should put shoes last.

I'm not sure if this is what you meant. Please let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: Hah, unfortunately the question is a little more complex than that. Your answer is correct as it literally puts `shoes` last because it's alphabetical, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I'd like to be able to put ***any*** category last based on my choosing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using aggregation as below. Am assuming the array is in a field called store and there are two other fields called name and age. So a typical record would be

```
{"name" : "a", "age" : 41, 
  "store" : [
        {name    :'obj1',
         category:'shoes'},
        {name    :'obj2',
         category:'hats'},
        {name    :'obj3',
         category:'jumpers'},
        {name    :'obj4',
         category:'shoes'}
       ]
}

 db.user.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$store"},
    {$sort:{"store.category":1}},
    {$group:{_id:{"name":"$name", "age":"$age"}, store:{$push:"$store"}}}
 )
```